# How to position dialog to current element with jquery ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, position

Javascript code:

```
currentElement=0;
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        position: {
                my: "top",
                at: "bottom",
                of: $( 'input[name='+currentElement+']' )
            },
        autoOpen: false,      
              show: { effect: "blind", duration: 1000 },
              hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 400 }  
        });     
        $( 'input[name^=opener]' ).click(function() {
            currentElement=this.id;
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );    
        });  
});
```

HTML code:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
    <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
    <td><input type="button" name="opener1" id=1></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
  <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
  <td><input type="button" name="opener2" id=2></td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">  <p>This is an animated dialog which
 is useful for    displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized
 and closed with the 'x' icon.</p></div>
```

But it doesn't work. More - I cannot close dialog. How to fix?

Comment: I tested your code and dialog close fine: http://jsfiddle.net/JSBL3/

Comment: which browser? I have tried on IE jsfiddle.net/JSBL3  - dialog doesn't displayed

Comment: on firefox it works. But JQuery should work on all browsers?

Comment: I have tried on IE 10